# how to self join a duplicate row to show as one row?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

example:

```
Code                  T_ID
12345                  1
12345                  2
```

I would like to return the following:

```
 Code             H_T          A_T
 12345             1            2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the restrictions here are (e.g., can you have more than two entries with code=12345?), but try this on for size:

```
SELECT code, h_t, a_t
FROM   (SELECT    code, MIN(t_id) AS h_t
        FROM      some_table
        GROUP BY  code) mins,
       (SELECT    code, MAX(t_id) AS a_t
        FROM      some_table
        GROUP BY  code) maxs
WHERE  mins.code = maxs.code
```

Comment: Yes, you can and will have more than 2 entries.. I will give that a try

Comment: this query doesn't assume anything about the number of entries per code, but if you could clarify your question and what exactly you're trying to achieve, it's be easier to provide you with the proper answer

Comment: It works only for those two entries, but doesn't work for all the codes in that table since it's using min,max. Excellent attempt though, thank you

Comment: @user1683987 You do not say in your problem statement that there will be more than two entries.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the answer, it would help to know if there are patterns / generalizations you can make, about the duplicates.

(1) Your example shows only 1 duplicate.  Is that representative, or is it ever more than 1 dup? 
If only 1 duplicate is possible, then the simplest solution would be without a JOIN... just GROUP BY:

```
SELECT Code 
   ,H_T = MIN(T_ID)
   ,A_T = MAX(T_ID)
FROM <tableName>  (NOLOCK) 
GROUP BY Code
```

(2) Your example shows consecutive natural numbers starting at 1.  Do they always start at 1?  Are they always consecutive?  How high can they go?
(Any valid generalizations like these would allow you to simplify the code... perhaps simpler than the below.)

For example, if we assume the duplicates are not consecutive and don't always start at 1, but we also assume that we only need to report *UP TO 10* duplicates, 
then we can introduce a ROW_NUMBER, (which WILL be consecutive and start at 1), and then link to that.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'zz_DupsReport_table1')
    DROP TABLE dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1
SELECT R_NUM = ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(PARTITION BY Code
                ORDER BY T_ID)
    ,Code
    ,T_ID
INTO dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1
FROM <tableName>  (NOLOCK) 
ORDER BY Code, T_ID

SELECT Code
    ,H_T = T01.T_ID
    ,A_T = T02.T_ID
    ,B_T = T03.T_ID
    ,C_T = T04.T_ID
    ,D_T = T05.T_ID
    ,E_T = T06.T_ID
    ,F_T = T07.T_ID
    ,G_T = T08.T_ID
    ,I_T = T09.T_ID
    ,J_T = T10.T_ID
    ,Over10found = CASE  WHEN Txx.Code IS NULL  THEN 'N'  ELSE 'Y'  END
FROM <tableName>  ORIG (NOLOCK) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T01 (NOLOCK)
      ON T01.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T01.R_NUM = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T02 (NOLOCK)
      ON T02.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T02.R_NUM = 2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T03 (NOLOCK)
      ON T03.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T03.R_NUM = 3
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T04 (NOLOCK)
      ON T04.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T04.R_NUM = 4
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T05 (NOLOCK)
      ON T05.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T05.R_NUM = 5
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T06 (NOLOCK)
      ON T06.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T06.R_NUM = 6
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T07 (NOLOCK)
      ON T07.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T07.R_NUM = 7
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T08 (NOLOCK)
      ON T08.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T08.R_NUM = 8
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T09 (NOLOCK)
      ON T09.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T09.R_NUM = 9
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  T10 (NOLOCK)
      ON T10.Code = ORIG.Code  AND T10.R_NUM = 10
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Code  
                   FROM dbo.zz_DupsReport_table1  SUBQ (NOLOCK)
                   WHERE SUBQ.R_NUM > 10
                  ) AS Txx
      ON Txx.Code = ORIG.Code
```

(3) If you want an unlimited number of duplicates (and therefore an unpredictable number of columns), you might have to get into *recursion*, and/or building your SELECT as a string, executed using EXEC. 
If that's the case, say so, and I can give more detail.

Hope that helps, 
--Doug

Comment: I edited the code under point (2):  took an extra comma out of the first SELECT, added an "ORDER BY" to the end of the first SELECT, and corrected the columnNames in the second SELECT, to only use columnName "H_T" once.